# What happens to requests when tomcat stops

Tags: http, tomcat, servlets, request

What happens to http requests that are being processed when you stop or restart tomcat in the "normal" way?
Will they be processed until the response is finished or are the http-threads interrupted?
Is there a way to configure graceful stopping?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Tomcat supports `unloadDelay` which waits till the configured time for unloading servlets.

This should configured in `context.xml` as follows:

```
<context unloadDelay="10000">
```

References:

- [Context Config guide](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html)
- [Tomcat unloadDelay attribute](http://autodidatastech.blogspot.in/2011/04/tomcat-unloaddelay-attribute.html)

Comment: Nice, so out of curiosity, does this cause tomcat to then reject new requests while still allowing the servlets to finish processing existing requests?

Comment: Is there any doc on how it rejects the requests? For example does it simply not allow the TCP socket to connect or does it send a RST back to the client?

Comment: It worked for me under linux with <Context path="/myapp" unloadDelay="10000"/> but only with upper letter _C_ontext.

Comment: @user2081279 where did you paster the above changes? In which file? I am confused. Thanks.

Comment: @mungaih pk there are several possibilities. One is to set it in server.xml like this: <Context path="/mycontextroot" unloadDelay="10000"/>, or you can set it in context.xml like this: <Context unloadDelay="10000"><Resource name="jdbc/imageserver" ... If you are instrested in context of docker/kubernetes, please see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51675180/how-to-gracefully-shutdown-servelts-in-tomcat-in-docker-container

Answer (score 1):

IT just kill the request and break the request-response link. And you get..

Unable to connect

```
  Browser can't establish a connection to the server at Host:port.

  The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
  If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network connection.
  If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Browser is permitted to access the Web.
```

That can not be handled.