# Graceful shutdown of tomcat on a kubernetes cluster

Tags: java, docker, tomcat, kubernetes

I am running a java application on tomcat in a k8s cluster, I am using a prestop lifecycle hook to run `/usr/local/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh` before the container gets terminated. Also defining a termination grace period of 60 secs.

expected behaviour: tomcat shutsdown gracefully when I kill a pod or delete a deployment.

actual behaviour: tomcat shutsdown abruptly.

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: sample
  annotations:
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: sample
      name: sample
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: sample
        name: sample
    spec:
      hostname: sample-web
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
      volumes:
       - name: splunk-inputs
         configMap:
           name: splunk-conf
           items:
           - key: inputs.conf
             path: ./inputs.conf
       - name: splunk-outputs
         configMap:
           name: splunk-conf
           items:
           - key: outputs.conf
             path: ./outputs.conf
       - name: docker-socket
         hostPath:
          path: /var/run/docker.sock
       - name: tomcat-log-common
         emptyDir: {} 
      containers:
      - name: sample
        image: sampleregistery.azurecr.io/root
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        lifecycle:
          preStop:
            exec:
              command: ["/usr/local/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh"]
```

Comment: Please post some of your YAML files.

Comment: sure @NicolaBen . please find the deployment section of my manifests below.

Comment: Re-edit your question adding your YAML manifests, please.

Comment: You declared 3 volumes, but you don't use them. Is your yaml complete? The tomcat image is public or in your repos?

Comment: there is another container(splunk forwarder) that is using the remaining volumes. the tomcat image i am using is from my organization's private repo.

Comment: What specifically happens differently in your case when Tomcat shuts down abruptly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

found the issue:

I was running this prestop lifecycle hook:

lifecycle:
preStop:
exec:
command: ["/usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh stop"]

It should be something like:

lifecycle:
preStop:
exec:
command: ["/usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh stop && sleep 30"]

In the first case, K8s was attempting to exit out of the lifecycle hook as soon as it invokes the shutdown.sh without waiting for tomcat to drain all threads.

it just takes about 5-10 secs depending upon your app. giving a sleep of 30 secs will keep the prestop hook active which should give enough time for tomcat to finish the shutdown process" .

Comment: Would terminationGracePeriodSeconds be a better approach in this case? Call catalina.sh stop and kubernetes will send the term signal and wait until terminationGracePeriodSeconds is over

Answer (score 2):

As of 2022, we tried adding the given command `/usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh stop && sleep 30` as our preStop hook. However, we endountered a `FailedPreStopHook` event displaying `exited with 137` (137 seems to be a memory error). After a few experiments, we have now the following setup to shutdown `tomcat` gracefully (see explanations below):

1. `terminationGracePeriodSeconds`set to 30s (the default - just *pro memoria*)
2. preStop hook is `/usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh stop 20`
3. in the `tomcat` image, we added `unloadDelay="10000"` to the `Context`

As the grace period starts when the preStop hook is invoked, we think 30s total should be enough for a graceful shutdown. The parameter `20` added to the `catalina stop` command gives `tomcat` 20s to shutdown gracefully and *wait for it* before exiting - under the control of `catalina.sh` / `tomcat`, which avoids the `FailedPreStopHook` event. Finally, the added `unloadDelay="10000"` should tell tomcat to wait at most 30s for the servlets to finish ongoing connections. Note that a) at the same time the preStop hook is invoked (i.e. the beginning of the termination process), the Pod status is set to `Terminating` and no more new connections are routed to it by ingresses / load balancers, and b) the preStop hook delays sending the `SIGTERM` to the process in then pod.

Here are some more resources we encountered:

- [https://www.containiq.com/post/exit-code-137#:~:text=Exit%20code%20137%20means%20a,host%20system%20to%20become%20unstable](https://www.containiq.com/post/exit-code-137#:%7E:text=Exit%20code%20137%20means%20a,host%20system%20to%20become%20unstable).
- https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/#container-hooks
- https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-termination
- http://muralitechblog.com/kubernetes-graceful-shutdown-of-pods/
- [What happens to requests when tomcat stops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11154533/what-happens-to-requests-when-tomcat-stops/11154770#11154770)
- [https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.1-doc/config/context.html#:~:text=will%20be%20used.-,unloadDelay,-Number%20of%20ms](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.1-doc/config/context.html#:%7E:text=will%20be%20used.-,unloadDelay,-Number%20of%20ms)
- https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.1-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/startup/Catalina.html

for a slightly more detailed explanation of the parameters for `catalina.sh`, you can also just invoke `catalina.sh --help`, giving:

```
/usr/local/apache-tomcat-10.0.22 # catalina.sh --help
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/local/tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/local/tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/local/tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /opt/java/openjdk
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/local/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Using CATALINA_OPTS:   
Usage: catalina.sh ( commands ... )
commands:
  debug             Start Catalina in a debugger
  debug -security   Debug Catalina with a security manager
  jpda start        Start Catalina under JPDA debugger
  run               Start Catalina in the current window
  run -security     Start in the current window with security manager
  start             Start Catalina in a separate window
  start -security   Start in a separate window with security manager
  stop              Stop Catalina, waiting up to 5 seconds for the process to end
  stop n            Stop Catalina, waiting up to n seconds for the process to end
  stop -force       Stop Catalina, wait up to 5 seconds and then use kill -KILL if still running
  stop n -force     Stop Catalina, wait up to n seconds and then use kill -KILL if still running
  configtest        Run a basic syntax check on server.xml - check exit code for result
  version           What version of tomcat are you running?
Note: Waiting for the process to end and use of the -force option require that $CATALINA_PID is defined
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the above but I did not get any result.

After lots of researching I have stepped in my way with this tool which it has ended up working really well.

https://github.com/Yelp/dumb-init#dumb-init

I hope that helps!!